# How to check is jQuery available for my module?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, module, custom, jquery

Magento as far as I know have it already loaded but jQuery functions won't work in my module.
What can I do with it ? How can I make sure I have an access to it ?
I would like to avoid jQuery conflicts.

Comment: Please describe your question more with HTML and jQuery code/functions that are not working/conflicting.

Comment: I just want use some jQuery functions in my module but if I not attach it to the module it won't work  :(

Comment: please describe your question MORE with code

Comment: If I would like to use jQuery in my module and if jQuery is not added with this module I says jQuery missing so I'm asking how can I use jQuery which should be already loaded with basic template/layout or not ?

Comment: this code will check if jQuery is available or not. `if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {console.log("jQuery is NOT available");} else {console.log("jQuery is available");}`